# how to make a new button in ListView?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I need to make an image button in the layout template of ListView,
when i click on the button it should open the insert template so i can insert a new record 
here is my ListView:

```
<asp:ListView ID="LVCategories" runat="server" DataKeyNames="CatID" DataSourceID="CategoriesDS" EnableModelValidation="True">
<AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <tr style="">
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CatIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CatID") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CatTitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CatTitle") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CatDescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CatDescription") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CatTitleArLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CatTitleAr") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CatDescriptionArLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CatDescriptionAr") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="PictureIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PictureID") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="PublishedCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Published") %>' Enabled="false" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="DisplayOrderLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DisplayOrder") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CreatedOnLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CreatedOn") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</AlternatingItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
    <tr style="">
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
            <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CatIDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CatID") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="CatTitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CatTitle") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="CatDescriptionTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CatDescription") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="CatTitleArTextBox" runat="server" ext='<%# Bind("CatTitleAr") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="CatDescriptionArTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CatDescriptionAr") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="PictureIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PictureID") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="PublishedCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Published") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="DisplayOrderTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DisplayOrder") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="CreatedOnTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CreatedOn") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</EditItemTemplate>
<EmptyDataTemplate>
    <table runat="server" style="">
        <tr>
            <td>
                No data was returned.
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <tr style="">
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert"  Text="Insert" />
            <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="CatIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CatID") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="CatTitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CatTitle") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="CatDescriptionTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CatDescription") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="CatTitleArTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CatTitleAr") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="CatDescriptionArTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CatDescriptionAr") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="PictureIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PictureID") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="PublishedCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Published") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="DisplayOrderTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DisplayOrder") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="CreatedOnTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CreatedOn") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</InsertItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr style="">
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CatIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CatID") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CatTitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CatTitle") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CatDescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CatDescription") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CatTitleArLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CatTitleAr") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CatDescriptionArLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CatDescriptionAr") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="PictureIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PictureID") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="PublishedCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Published") %>' Enabled="false" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="DisplayOrderLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DisplayOrder") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CreatedOnLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CreatedOn") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<LayoutTemplate>
    <table runat="server">
        <tr runat="server">
            <td runat="server">
                <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                    <tr runat="server" style="">
                        <th runat="server">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnNew" runat="server" CommandName="New" />
                             <%--<asp:ImageButton ID="NewCatbtn" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" ImageUrl="~/ADMIN/themes/Img/New.png" AlternateText="Click Here To Add New" OnClick="OpenTheInsertTemplates"/>--%>
                             </th>
                        <th runat="server">CatTitle</th>
                        <th runat="server">CatDescription</th>
                        <th runat="server">CatTitleAr</th>
                        <th runat="server">atDescriptionAr</th>
                        <th runat="server">PictureID</th>
                        <th runat="server">Published</th>
                        <th runat="server">DisplayOrder</th>
                        <th runat="server">CreatedOn</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr runat="server">
            <td runat="server" style=""></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
<SelectedItemTemplate>
    <tr style="">
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CatIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CatID") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CatTitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CatTitle") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CatDescriptionLabel" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Eval("CatDescription") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CatTitleArLabel" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Eval("CatTitleAr") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CatDescriptionArLabel" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Eval("CatDescriptionAr") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="PictureIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PictureID") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="PublishedCheckBox" runat="server" 
                Checked='<%# Eval("Published") %>' Enabled="false" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="DisplayOrderLabel" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Eval("DisplayOrder") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CreatedOnLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CreatedOn") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</SelectedItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="cmdInsert" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />

Protected Sub ListView1_ItemInserting (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e as ListViewEditEventArgs)
    ' ... '
End Sub
```

Comment: yes i did but it's not working and what i want is a button when i click on it it should show me the insert template so i can insert a new record

Comment: this command will insert a new record but what i want is to show the insert template !!!

thanks for your help

Comment: @HAJJAJ Doesn't it switch ListView to Insert mode?

Comment: Insert can only be called on an insert item. Ensure only the InsertTemplate has a button with CommandName=Insert. 


this is the error when i uesd that button

Comment: @HAJJAJ Take a look on [this](http://forums.asp.net/p/1537798/3739047.aspx) ASP.NET forum article

Comment: I have an Idea but i couldn't make it !!!

I want to make a button in the Layout template not in the item template in the listvew  ,and when i click on that button it should execute vb code to show the insert template somthing like this code :"Protected Sub LVCategories_ItemEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewEditEventArgs)
        LVCategories.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.LastItem
    End Sub"

Comment: the problem is i cant find that button in the list view ,when i click on that button it's not execute my code!!!

i Used this code but it doesn't work :
 Dim insertbtn As Button = LVCategories.FindControl("btnNew")

Comment: @HAJJAJ Such controls as `ListView` work next way: when you click on a button causing post back, controls checks itself what is happened, i.e. checks `CommandName`, and if it's well-known, then reacts. So `Button.CommandName="Insert"` should switch control to insert mode without any events

Comment: @HAJJAJ Also check out [ListView.InsertItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.insertitem.aspx)

Comment: I change my mind and i used something else:

 Sub Commandd(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewCommandEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemCommand
        Try
            If e.CommandName.Equals("Delete") Then
                'Other code
                Dim Idlabel As Label = e.Item.FindControl("ImageIDLabel")
                Session("ID") = Idlabel.Text()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

I added this one to my behind code and it's working very will :)

thank you for your great help .

Answer (score 0):

this example has been solved like this :
ASPX file:

```
 <th runat="server">
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"  Text="new" CommandName="new" ImageUrl="~/ADMIN/themes/Img/DeleteBtn.png" />
                                </th>
```

the VB.net Code:

```
Sub deletedd(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewCommandEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemCommand
    Try
        If e.CommandName.Equals("Delete") Then
            'this to take a value from any control
            Dim Idlabel As Label = e.Item.FindControl("ImageIDLabel")
            Session("ID") = Idlabel.Text()
        End If
        If e.CommandName.Equals("new") Then
            'Other code
            ListView1.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.FirstItem
        End If
        If e.CommandName.Equals("Cancel") Then
            'Other code
            ListView1.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.None
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try


End Sub
```